# error when import panda the second time in mac python 2.7

Tags: python

I cannot use `import pandas as pd` the second time. At the beginning, I type this it worked very well. After I close the terminal, reopen it, and type it again, it is said 'pd' is not defined...

This happened both in Apple Python and Anaconda. I have tried deleting one and only use the other, but the error happens in the same way.

Comment: https://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/ This blog has helped me solve my problem. Hope it will help anyone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but if this behavior is what you mean, this is normal behavior. I do not have pandas, but with any other library should be the same:

```
>>> import requests as pd
>>> print pd.__version__
2.9.1
>>> exit()
Abel-Guzman-Sanchezs-MacBook-Air:~ cncuser$ python 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print pd.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
>>>
```

Every-time you execute code you have to import the libraries that you need. And just in case you can import the same library more than once:

```
>>> import requests as pd
>>> import requests as pd
>>>
```

Edit1:
I installed `pandas` using `pip install pandas` to show you the same:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print pd.__version__
0.18.1
>>> exit()
Abel-Guzman-Sanchezs-MacBook-Air:~ cncuser$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print pd.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
>>> import requests as pd
>>> print pd.__version__
2.9.1
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am very new to Python. Each time in Python I call pandas as 'import pandas as pd', but when I do this the second time and later 'pd' is no longer being recognized, and I don't know why. There are a lot of questions related to "errors when importing pandas" on stack overflow, my situation is pretty much the same. The only difference is that it did work for once. So I don't know what is going on and how can I avoid this happening next time. Thanks again.